# Convert integer to float

Tags: python, integer, boolean

I am trying to write a function that converts integers to floats, and leave booleans and strings as they are.

I have defined the following function:

```
def if_int_to_float(value):

    if isinstance(value, bool):

        return value

    elif isinstance(value, int):

        return float(value)

    else:

        return value
```

When used extensively, I have found this function a bit slow. Any idea to improve its performance/ making it more pythonic?

Comment: What do you mean when you say slow?

Comment: Question: why do you need this function in the first place? This seems like something where if you need a float you can just cast to `float()` when necessary.

Comment: You check for a `bool`, however you don't do anything special if it is, so you can remove that.

Comment: This code is run as part of a larger program and after playing around with cProfile, I see that a good part of the execution time is eaten up by this function call even though it's not called too much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can perhaps combine your if conditions. This will help since we short-circuit the if conditions based on the inputs, so that might make your code faster!

```
def if_int_to_float(value):

    #If not boolean and int or float, convert to float
    if not isinstance(value, bool) and isinstance(value, int) or isinstance(value,float):
        return float(value)

    #Else return value
    else:
        return value

print(if_int_to_float('a'))
print(if_int_to_float(1))
print(if_int_to_float(1.0))
print(if_int_to_float(True))
```

The output will be

```
a
1.0
1.0
True
```

Comment: It works, thanks but Fuzzbury's solution is faster!

Comment: Sure thing, may I know how you judged it as faster? Also using type is bad and even the docs suggests to use isinstance

Comment: Thanks Devesh, just running cProfile against my code with the new function. However, after reading more about `type`, I have chosen your solution.

Comment: Sure thanks, the earlier chosen solution was using an unnecessary multiplication in the code, whereas just chaining `ifinstance` is enough :)

Answer (score 3):

You can remove one check and write on a single line to get a slight speed improvement when passing floats or strings. The bool case is already very fast.

Isinstance() is causing you some trouble here as bools also match int hence your first if statement, so you could use type() instead

```
def if_int_to_float(value):
    return value * 1.0 if type(value) == int else value
```

Comment: This works like a charm and makes my code faster. Thank you!

Comment: If I could ask, how do you know @NicolasBerthier that this is faster? Also using `type` is bad, and you should always use `isinstance` to check for types as per python docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#type

Comment: Hi Devesh, just by running my code through cProfile and replacing the function.

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
def if_int_to_float(value):

    if type(value) == int:

        return float(value)

    else:

        return value
```

Answer (score 1):

when data is in list, use `lambda`

```
data=[1,3,'j','oo']
sol = list(map(lambda x: float(x) if type(x)=='int' else x, data))
print(sol)
```

output

```
[1.0, 3.0, 'j', 'oo']
```

or use function to test the individual value

```
def fun_int_to_float(value):
    if type(value)=='int':
        return float(value)
    return value
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. My data is not in a list but I'll keep this around if I need it.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try `type()` function and get the result. Or you can use exception handling to handle this type of problem. But in that case, as pointed out in the comments, in case of `bool` values it'd covert `True` to `1.0` and `False` to `0.0`.

```py
#using type() function
def if_int_to_float(value):
    if type(value) == int:
        return float(value)
    else:
        return value
```

Comment: This converts boolean to 1.0 !